Powershell Script Function Select and SaveAs
I have a script what should do the following:
Open a File with a Dialog Box and save the selected File as a compressed Archive and automaticly create the Output on a Destination (say C:\Temp)
The Dialog Box I have made. However I cannot for the life of me figure a way out to save the selected File as a compressed Archive=Zip, optimaly with a password.
This is what I have created so far:
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
Filter = 'Filetype (*.mp4)|*.mp4'
}
$null = $FileBrowser.ShowDialog()

Hopefully someone has an Idea.
Thanks in advance
Tod
Select a file in a Dislog Box and Output a compressed archive = Zip file

To get this script to work you have to install the module 7Zip4Powershell, it should work without having 7zip installed, thats the problem i was having i installed 7zip called it and then it worked.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
    InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
    Filter = 'Filetype (*.mp4)|*.mp4'
}

if ($FileBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK') {
    $selectedFile = $FileBrowser.FileName
    $output = "C:\Temp\Exit"
    
    $password = Read-Host "Enter password"

    $sevenZipPath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

    $arguments = "a -tzip `"$output`" `"$selectedFile`" -p$password"

    Start-Process -FilePath $sevenZipPath -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait

    Write-Host "Zip Created"
}


This has actially done it! Awesome, thank you so much.

Try this
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

# Select a file using a dialog window
$FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
Filter = 'Filetype (*.mp4)|*.mp4'}

if ($FileBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK') {
$selectedFile = $FileBrowser.FileName

# Request password for the ZIP archive
$password = Read-Host "Enter password for the ZIP archive"

# Path to save the ZIP archive
$outputPath = "C:\Temp\output.zip"

# Create a ZIP archive with a password
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($selectedFile, $outputPath, 'Optimal', $true)

# Add password to the ZIP archive
$zipFile = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($outputPath, 'Update')
$zipFile.SetPassword($password)
$zipFile.Dispose()

Write-Host "File successfully saved as a ZIP archive with a password in $outputPath"}


Thank you for the input.
It does create a output.zip. However it is empty. (i used an mp4 file)
It says something about the directory not being valid and that the there is no method for the function "setpassword"
I copied your whole input and run it. gets the mentiond errors.
Thank you so much, allready a step closer!
Tod
